# Using MMULT to populate Gantt chart

Tags: matrix, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gantt-chart

Trying to use `MMULT` to populate this Gantt chart with a single formula.

This is what I'm trying that's not working

```
=MMULT(--($E4:E<=G$1:1),--($F4:F>=G$1:1))`
```

(I have it reversed in the image by accident; the same result though)

edit: This seems to be closer, but still not filling all cells...

```
=MMULT(IF($E4:$E<=G$1:$1,1,0),IF($F4:$F>=G$1:$1,1,0))
```

This is what I'm using to get the proper outcome, but I have to drag across every cell.

```
=IF(AND(G$1>=$E4,G$1<=$F4),"x",)
```

What am I doing wrong with the `MMULT` formula?  Tried wrapping in `ARRAYFORMULA` without luck.  Tried using `COUNTIF`, no luck there either...

Here is my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wrWUFNqwEm7hhOQROSAtOVPDN7Ca7UYNlf1A5KZ8Qns/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with the MMULT formula, but shouldn't the number of columns in the first matrix be equal to the number of rows in the 2nd one for the multiplication to take place? Maybe it is but I'm just not seeing that in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(($E4:E<=G$1:1)*($F4:F>=G$1:1)=1, "x", ))
```

[image: 6]